# Looking for good Java audio compression library

Tags: java, audio, open-source, codec

I am looking for a solid open source audio compression library for java. I am working on a closed sourced project, so no copy left licenses. But I am interested in both lossless and lossy.

Comment: A lot of people (game programmers I know) use ogg/vorbis. http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/ 
http://www.jcraft.com/jorbis/tutorial/Tutorial.html
It is lossy, but perhaps a bit less so than mp3.

Answer (score 3):

http://flac.sourceforge.net/license.html <-- BSD license / lossless

http://jflac.sourceforge.net/ << Apache license / lossless

Comment: Have you used jFlac before? Can you verify its reliability? I believe the license is GNU public which is a copy left license. Thanks.

Comment: I have not used jflac, hopefully someone else can comment on it's reliability. See right sidebar for license: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jflac/. The license file in the download doesn't say apache, but looks like it to me.

Comment: The license in the distribution I have is definitely GNU public. Also, it looks like jFlac died before anyone ported the "co" part of the codec. So that's really just a "dec".