# Which data store can handle TB of audio calls in SWING

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design, data-structures

Which database best suits the following scenario:

I have created a java application which stores audio calls to the local file system. The application, in order to play audio calls, retrieves the metadata from a database (MySQL), which has one column with the location to the call on the local HD.

The issue I have now is that the amount of audio calls is HUGE (around 50 TB)

What should I do to handle such amount of data

The application is built in JAVA SWING

**EDIT:**

I am interested in which database can handle such amount of data.
I have heard about Hadoop but seems it is very good only for batch processing not for real time querying.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: 50 TB is not huge.  You need to define "best" to get a useful answer.  You are asking for opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider compressing the audio files. Ideally, with lossless compression but if necessary, with lossy compression (you can probably get away with a low bitrate if the audio calls are only speech). Another user suggested the following Java compression libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486007/2557554

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look into this later on. What I am interested in right now is the design of my datastore. I need some server which is not expensive and that can handle such amount of data